# What is the symmetry of the Penrose tiling?

Tags: symmetry

What is the symmetry of the [Penrose tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling)? Simply C5 or bigger?

Any simple proof that the tiling is a complete cover of the plane?

Comment: Could you provide a physical motivation for that? As it stands, I see a pure math question.

Comment: it is a quasi symmetry. It is so obvious that it covers the plane, it would only be a passing thought of one line to a tiles-mathematician. the angles of the tiles always add up to 360 and the edges are always the same length, it would not be possible to have a crack in the coverage. that should be enough to prove it covers a 360 isometric plane.

Comment: It likely depends in the tiling, but usually I see D5 or D10.